# Best way to set requests in background

Tags: ios, design-patterns, core-data, backgroundworker, asihttprequest

In my iOS5-App I do a lot of Request, parsing the results and storing them in CoreData simultaneously.

For doing the requests I use asynchronous ASIHttpRequest.

But the app has perfromance problems while this requests are running. What is a good approach to to this in the background? And how do I avoid conflicts with the context when storing the results to the db? All "commits" are performed in the main-thread because I had problems when putting the requests in a backgroundque.

Can you give me an example or a good pattern to use in my app?

Comment: What problems did you have when you put the requests in a bg queue?

Comment: Use the Instruments profiler to figure out which code is causing your performance issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ASI is no longer being supported a lot of people switched to [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).
There's also the minimalistic approach of using [NSURLConnections with Blocks](http://blog.logichigh.com/2010/09/12/cocoa-blocks/).